# How to check if Key exists in a Dictionary and then replace its value if it does when using .ToDictionary()

Tags: c#, dictionary, httpwebresponse

I have a dictionary as following:

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> loginDetails = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

I have the following strings:

```
result = rdr.ReadToEnd();
string parseResult = result.Replace(",", System.Environment.NewLine).Replace("\"", "")
.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "");
```

I update the dictionary in the code as follows by getting keys and values from a string parseResult:

```
loginDetails = parseResult.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)
.ToDictionary(x => x.Split(':')[0], x => x.Split(':')[1]);
```

I was wondering how I can check if a key exists in the dictionary and if it does, replace its value with the newly obtained value while maintaining .ToDictionary()

Thanks.

Comment: ToDictionary is creating a new dictionary instance that replaces the existing instance each time it runs.   If you want to preserve existing dictionary entries and add to them, you should use a foreach instead.  Something like `parseResult.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None).ForEach(x => loginDetails[x.Split( ':')[0]] = x.Split(':')[1])`

Comment: why do you need to use `ToDictionary` ? could you just filter on SQL side?

Comment: @Grax32 "ToDictionary is creating a new dictionary instance that replaces the existing instance".  No, it does not modify or replace anything.  It just creates a new dictionary.

Comment: @Zer0 The sample code assigns the result of ToDictionary to the loginDetails variable, replacing the previous instance of the dictionary.

Comment: @Grax32 I thought you were referring to the method ToDictionary itself.  But yeah, the code above is replacing an existing dictionary with the return value.

Comment: @Grax32 - So, basically, every time the .ToDictionary() part runs, my dictionary called "loginDetails" is replaced with new, fresh elements?

So, if it contained 1 = a, 2 = b, 3 = c, and I call .ToDictionary(), then 1 = a,  2 = b, 3 = c, are erased from loginDetails, and then replaced by whatever I get again?

Comment: Yes.  You are completely replacing your dictionary with the results of the `ToDictionary` call.  So be careful that it returns all the data you want.  And nothing else holds a reference to the old dictionary.

Comment: I think this works great in my case. Normally, when you try to add to a dictionary, it skips over if the key is already present. One of the values that I am getting is a session token that I store in a global variable once I call the .ToDictionary(). I just wanted to get new values each time and as you said that that's exactly what's happening, then it means I am getting the latest values. So it works for me. Thank you!